# How to make random sample from dataframe on unique values in R

Tags: r, random

I have a dataframe from which I want to draw a random sample--not just any sample but one that contains exactly one randomly sampled row from each of the unique values in the column `word`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  word = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = T),
  value = sample(1:10, 50, replace = T)
)
head(df)
  word value
1    B     1
2    D     5
3    C     8
4    E     2
5    E     6
6    A     3
```

What I've done to solve this problem is this:
1. Store unique words in vector:

```
UniqueWords <- unique(df$word)
```

2. Set up a `for` loop:

```
for(i in UniqueWords){
  df_sample[i,] <- df[sample(1:nrow(df[df$word==UniqueWords[i], ]), 1), ]
}
```

The loop, however, does not produce the correct result. How can it be tweaked or, alternatively, what other method can be used?

Comment: Do you want to get one random row for each `word` ? `df %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  sample_n(1)
`

Comment: Correct. Since there are 5 different words, the desired df should contain 5 rows. In which package is `%>%`?

Comment: okay...that was a `dplyr` solution. There are many more alternatives in the linked target.